# To map RGB to Parula in Matlab

Tags: image, matlab, colors, rgb, parula

There are functions such as *rgb2hsv*, *rgb2ind*, *rgb2lab* and *rgb2xyz* in converting RGB colormap to another one - in Matlab R2014b where the colormap *Parula* is introduced. 
However, I cannot find any solution to convert the RGB colormap to *Parula* i.e. the current default colormap of Matlab. 
I can set the colormap to be with the figure, but not convert the image as follows.
I started to think the benefits of Parula in contrast to HSV in one part of removing black and its neighbor colors in a picture, for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29801704/54964).

Pseudocommand

```
im = imread('https://i.stack.imgur.com/cFOSp.png'); 
hsv = rgb2parula(im); % Pseudocommand similar for HSV: hsv = rgb2hsv(im);
imshow(hsv);
```

which gives

[image]

which is one reason for the quantization noise in later stages of image processing and bad morphological removal, as indicated in the previous thread.

**How can you map RGB to Parula in Matlab?**

### User-made Parulas

I think we need a customized *Parula* because the function *rgb2parula* is not available. 
Proposal [here](http://www.gnuplotting.org/data/parula.pal) which a variant for Gnuplot about the colormap. 
How can you convert this piece of code to Matlab?

Comment: I think you should mention which version you're using. I believe Matlab changed their colour map/scheme for default plots back in the 2014a/b version. Please correct me if I misunderstood the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not really possible, because `Parula` does not contain all the possible RGB values. If you think about it, every Matlab colormap is just a subset of the RGB ensemble. In mathematical terms `rgb2hsv` is an isomorphism, but there cannot be such isomorphism between RGB and a colormap (even the `hsv` colormap, which does not take all possible HSV values).

Then for a given RGB triplet you can try to find the nearest RGB triplet inside the Parula colormap. Something like:

```
cm = parula(256);
RGB = rand(1,3);

d2 = (cm(:,1)-RGB(1)).^2 + (cm(:,2)-RGB(2)).^2 + (cm(:,3)-RGB(3)).^2;
[~, mi] = min(d2);
```

and `cm(mi,:)` will be the nearest color to RGB in Parula according to this metric. But of course, this is an imperfect solution.

Comment: I think this is what he was getting at. Not a perfect conversion, but round to the closest colour.

Comment: *(even the hsv colormap, which does not tacke all possible HSV values).* Do you mean that hsv colormap which does not tackle all possible RGB values?

Comment: @Masi: There are two reasons: first the `hsv` function creates a vector of RGB components where _only_ hue varies, the saturation and value being constant. For instance, it is easy to see that there is no white and no black in the outputs of `hsv`. Second, as  hsv outputs a `n-by-3`array, well you can't map all the possibe hue values with just `n` color, right ?

Comment: Yes. - Can you give an example how you apply your Parula to the image `im` in Pseudocode? I did not get the example.

Comment: @Masi: Sure. The method in the solution is just to evaluate the "distance" between your color and the colors in your colormap. For this, I compute the sum of the quadratic difference for the three component (just as you would do for points with XYZ coordinates and use Pythagore's theorem) and then search for the minimal distance with `min`, well in this case the minimal squared distance which is the same. Is that clearer ?

Comment: You say HSV is an isomorphism of RGB mathematically. Why Parula cannot be isomorphism of RGB? There are also gabs in real line so no problem in not having all colors of RGB in Parula.

Comment: @Masi Sorry for being unclear. When I evoke HSV in the isomorphism analogy, i am refering to the general method to describe colors with hue-saturation-value parameters and not the matlab `hsv` function. The name of the `hsv` function is misleading, hence my comment on it.

Comment: Thank you for clarification! I added an example of optimized Parula in Gnuplot to the body. The function `rgb2parula` is not available officially so I think the only option is to do it.

Comment: I opened a new thread about a related problem here in reading Parula image into Matlab: http://stackoverflow.com/q/29990133/54964