# To imread Parula image in Matlab without losing resolution

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, resolution

There is no bijection between RGB and Parula, discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29807223/54964). 
I am thinking how to do well the image processing of files in Parula. 
This challenge has been developed from this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29800089/54964) about removing black color from ECG images by extending the case to a generalized problem with Parula colors.

Data:

[image]

which is generated by

```
[X,Y,Z] = peaks(25);
imgParula = surf(X,Y,Z);
view(2);
axis off;
```

It is not the point of this thread to use this code in your solution to read the second image.

Code:

```
[imgParula, map, alpha] = imread('https://i.stack.imgur.com/tVMO2.png');
```

where `map` is `[]` and `alpha` is a completely white image. Doing `imshow(imgParula)` gives

[image]

where you see a lot of interference and lost of resolution because Matlab reads images as RGB, although the actual colormap is `Parula`. 
Resizing this picture does not improve resolution.

**How can you read image into corresponding colormap in Matlab?** 
I did not find any parameter to specify the colormap in reading.

Comment: It's not completely clear to me: do you want to retrieve the array that has been used to create the first image (with `imshow` and the parula colormap) ?

Comment: Yes. I want to retrieve the data that has been used to create the first Parula image. I want to be able to create the first image from reading the file back to Matlab and then plotting it again.

Comment: OK. If you don't know what was the setting of `caxis` (_i.e._ the colormap's range) there is an indetermination. For instance, the blue could be any value depending on this setting ... A solution would give you an array ranged between 0 and 1 for instance, which may not be the initial data range.

Comment: An image file is not meant to represent arbitrary data, but graphics, which may or may not be representing data. If you want to store data generated in Matlab, use a mat file or maybe another binary or text-based file format.

Comment: Can you provide code for your "Data" image? The images appear to have identical colors on my machine (OS X, Safari). Also, color profiles might be useful, but you'd have to go to TIFF instead of PNG in that case.

Comment: I think I see how to do it and will try a solution in a few hours / tomorrow when I'm back home, if no solution has been posted in between.

Comment: @horchler I provided the code to generate the first image but it is not the point to use this code for the solution.

Comment: I think it can be done in the following way: convert the black lines into white, apply regionprops on the non-white pixels, use the barycenters to map the regions on a regular grid and, finally, average the color on the region and map it to the parula colormap by looking at the closest color. Unfortunately, the first step depends too much on how the initial  image has been generated (format, resolution), and the fact that the black grid is not completely black.

Comment: Can you give a practical example? How can we improve the first step?

Comment: @Ratbert: see my attempt below. I'm not sure I covered every aspect of the problem – at least as you detailed – but I did implement a solution to find the "closest" color.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**The Problem**

There is a [one-to-one mapping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Injective_function) from indexed colors in the [`parula`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colormap.html#inputs) colormap to RGB triplets. However, no such one-to-one mapping exists to reverse this process to convert a `parula` indexed color back to RGB (indeed there are an infinite number ways to do so). Thus, there is no one-to-one correspondence or [bijection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bijection) between the two spaces. The plot below, which shows the R, G, and B values for each `parula` index, makes this clearer.

[image: Parula to RGB plot]

This is the case for most indexed colors. Any solution to this problem will be non-unique.

**A Built-in Solution**

I after playing around with this a bit, I realized that there's already a built-in function that may be sufficient: [`rgb2ind`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rgb2ind.html), which converts RGB image data to indexed image data. This function uses [`dither`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dither.html) (which in turn calls the mex function `ditherc`) to perform the inverse colormap transformation.

Here's a demonstration that uses JPEG compression to add noise and distort the colors in the original `parula` index data:

```
img0 = peaks(32);                     % Generate sample data
img0 = img0-min(img0(:));
img0 = floor(255*img0./max(img0(:))); % Convert to 0-255
fname = [tempname '.jpg'];            % Save file in temp directory
map = parula(256);                    % Parula colormap
imwrite(img0,map,fname,'Quality',50); % Write data to compressed JPEG
img1 = imread(fname);                 % Read RGB JPEG file data

img2 = rgb2ind(img1,map,'nodither');  % Convert RGB data to parula colormap

figure;
image(img0);                          % Original indexed data
colormap(map);
axis image;

figure;
image(img1);                          % RGB JPEG file data
axis image;

figure;
image(img2);                          % rgb2ind indexed image data
colormap(map);
axis image;
```

This should produce images similar to the first three below.

[image: Example original data and converted images]

**Alternative Solution: Color Difference**

Another way to accomplish this task is by comparing the difference between the colors in the RGB image with the RGB values that correspond to each colormap index. The standard way to do this is by [calculating Δ*E*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_difference#Delta_E) in the [CIE L*a*b*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lab_color_space) color space. I've implemented a form of this in a general function called [`rgb2map`](https://github.com/horchler/rgb2map/blob/master/rgb2map.m) that can be [downloaded from my GitHub](https://github.com/horchler/rgb2map). This code relies on [`makecform`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/makecform.html) and [`applycform`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/applycform.html) in the Image Processing Toolbox to convert from RGB to the 1976 CIE L*a*b* color space.

The following code will produce an image like the one on the right above:

```
img3 = rgb2map(img1,map);

figure;
image(img3);                          % rgb2map indexed image data
colormap(map);
axis image;
```

For each RGB pixel in an input image, `rgb2map` calculates the color difference between it and every RGB triplet in the input colormap using the [CIE 1976](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_difference#CIE76) standard. The `min` function is used to find the index of the minimum Δ*E* (if more than one minimum value exists, the index of the first is returned). More sophisticated means can be used to select the "best" color in the case of multiple Δ*E* minima, but they will be more costly.

**Conclusions**

As a final example, I used [an image of the namesake Parula bird](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/ea/Parula_pitiayumi_-Fecapi,_Piraju,_Sao_Paulo,_Brasil-8.jpg) to compare the two methods in the figure below. The two results are quite different for this image. If you manually adjust `rgb2map` to use the more complex [CIE 1994](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_difference#CIE94) color difference standard, you'll get yet another rendering. However, for images that more closely match the original `parula` colormap (as above) both should return more similar results. Importantly, `rgb2ind` benefits from calling mex functions and is almost 100 times faster than `rgb2map` despite several optimizations in my code (if the CIE 1994 standard is used, it's about 700 times faster).

[image: RGB image of bird converted using two methods]

Lastly, those who want to learn more about colormaps in Matlab, should read this [four-part MathWorks blog post](http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/category/colormap/) by Steve Eddins on the new `parula` colormap.

*Update 6-20-2015:* [`rgb2map`](https://github.com/horchler/rgb2map) code described above updated to use different color space transforms, which improves it's speed by almost a factor of two.

Comment: `rgb2map` seems to be better to eye than `rgb2ind` in all colors. `rgb2map` seems to burn through with the yellow color. **Why does this burning through occur in `rgb2map`? Any way to avoid it?** - Another hope is that if you could maintain the grid of vertical and horizontal lines in some of your examples. I would like to see how different functions affect the lines in different environments. Those lines are particularly put there for the challenge for a particular reason.

Comment: @Masi: I'm guessing it's due to the use of just a simple `min` function to find the closest color match. At the extremes, i.e., near black, white, and fully-saturated colors, it's likely that there will be multiple minima, in which case the first will be used. This results in many pixels showing up as one of the extreme values on the colormap. Potential ways around this: 1) reorder the colormap so a different color is always selected, 2) randomly choose (or another scheme) when multiple minima are present, 3) use weighting to bias particular channels or combinations thereof to vary the choice.

Comment: The `parula` colormap doesn't include black and white. Your images appear to be screen grabs and have black lines despite using indexed colors because you're viewing the data not as an image, but as a 3-D object via `surf` (black is the default edge color irrespective of the data). A completely different process or special cases will be required to handle this. It would perhaps be better to avoid the problem in the first place by pre-processing and saving files differently.

Comment: The easiest method for handling artifacts like your grid lines might be to modify the colormap slightly. Try the examples in my answer with `map = [0 0 0; parula(254); 1 1 1];`.

Comment: Is there any standard color chosen for grids in Parula? If not, then again the choose of any color for the grids is going to be only one selection.